# How do I serve an html file in my Web App with ASP.NET without the WWWROOT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Learning Visual Studios ASP.NET Application how do I attached html file to my project?
in startup.cs

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        **app.UseStaticFiles();**
    }
}
```

My index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dutch Treat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dutch Treat</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The instructions say to move into **wwwroot** but there no **wwwroot**.
Here a pic of what I have

[image: snapshot of my code]

Comment: I suggest you watch this if you are learning asp.net as it helped me a lot

Comment: @TERMINATOR there's no link to any videos.

Comment: Here sorry : https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oW8nviYduHq7bmKode-p8Wy

Comment: Here is an [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) of static files.You can create a wwwroot.You can also serve files outside of web root with a folder you want.

Comment: Hi @RichardBrescher, any updates about this case? if the answer did help achieve your requirement, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you create project using a empty project template, like below.

[image]

It does help create ASP.NET Core project, not ASP.NET project. If you'd like to compare differences between them, you can check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> How do I serve an html file in my Web App with ASP.NET without the WWWROOT?

As you shared in your code, calling the [`UseStaticFiles` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/owin.staticfileextensions.usestaticfiles?view=owin-4.1) in Startup.Configure, which enables static files to be served.

But please note that `UseStaticFiles` default to the file provider pointing at `wwwroot`, you can manually create the folder with name "wwwroot" and move `index.html` etc static files to it. Or create a folder with a name (such as "MyStaticFiles" etc) you expect, then configure static file serving from that folder, like below.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles"))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wwwroot is nothing but a folder within the project. If it does not exists, you could just add a folder named wwwroot directly under your project and then add the html file under it.